# iterm2 triggers copy/paste, import/export

Tags: mac, terminal, iterm2

On the Mac's iTerm2 terminal, I have set a bunch of highlight text options in Preferences->Profiles->(select a profile)->Advanced (tab)->Triggers->Edit.  Mine is specifically to highlight the text [debug,info,warn,error] in log files.  I want to copy this over to the other profiles.  Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

For internet spelunkers like myself, this can now be done (sort of) using the

> `Other Actions -> Bulk Copy from Selected Profile`

feature (under the list of profiles on the Profiles preference pane). I can't find a reference to it in the [docs](https://www.iterm2.com/documentation.html), but it allows you to copy settings from one profile to others. The downside is that the "bulk" part means you can't *just* copy the Triggers - you have to copy *all* the Advanced settings for that profile.

I'm using iTerm2 build 3.3.6.